# Opencv gpu::split not working properly

Tags: opencv, split, gpu

I've being trying to split 2 channel GpuMat using gpu::split. Given below is my code

```
    gpu::GpuMat gpu_zeros; gpu_zeros.upload(Mat::zeros(Size(J,I), CV_32F));
    gpu::GpuMat splitted_gpu[] = {gpu_zeros,gpu_zeros};
    gpu::split(complex_gpu,splitted_gpu); // Here complex_gpu is a 2 channel GpuMat. 

    // Downloading the splitted GpuMat to check the results
    Mat t1,t2;
    splitted_gpu[0].download(t1);
    splitted_gpu[1].download(t2);
```

But when I check t1 and t2 , they both have channel 2 of the complex_gpu GpuMat. The channel 1 data is missing.

Have I done anything wrong ? Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Note : I'm using them inside mexFunctions.
Opencv version is 2.4

Comment: Have you tried initializing it like `gpu::GpuMat splitted_gpu;` only..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the tip scap3y.
The problem was with the initializing.

When replaced the first two lines with the below code, problem got solved.

> gpu::GpuMat splitted_gpu[2];